# Import Code from FPGA Board (Spartan 3E)

Tags: hardware, verilog, vhdl, fpga, spartan

Is there any way to import code from an already programmed FPGA board, in this case, it is a Spartan 3E board. That is to say, verilog code has already been uploaded to it, so I would like a way to receive the code back in the computer since I have lost the copy. I uploaded the code with Xilinx ISE, but am not sure if it is possible to go the other way around.

I really appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IF you mean the FPGA bitstream, Impact should be able to read it out. But if you want to get back to the source Verilog files... forget it, sorry!

(If it's a Xilinx board you can just download all the code it originally came with though :)

Comment: Impact is the tool which loads the bitstream over JTAG into the FPGA.  On Windows you can find it in Xilinx ISE Design Suite..ISE..Accessories..iMPACT off the start menu.